# How to install Ubuntu to a .disk file

Tags: wubi, custom-installer, disk-image

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.3 Live USB

I have created a 25GB .disk file that is located on the Windows partition. (Same as WUBI)

I have done: `sudo losetup /dev/loop1 /mnt/<disk file location>/root.disk.`

I can now see that .disk file using disk utility and it has a ext4 filesystem.

How can I add this disk (and a swap .disk file) to the Ubuntu Installer so I can install Ubuntu into the .disk files.

Comment: You don't.  You need to follow the normal install procedure to create a partition for Ubuntu.

Comment: Like I said, you don't; the installer does not support that ( at least, it won't be able to install grub ).  WUBI does it with a dirty hack and a dos build of grub legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi uses two distinct techniques. The disk image technique downloads a preinstalled disk image file that has been compressed. Then it uncompresses this as the `root.disk` and then uses `resize2fs` to make it whatever size you want. Then it remains to create the user account at login which it does with a preseed file:

```
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean false
d-i time/zone string $(timezone)
d-i passwd/user-fullname string $(user_full_name)
d-i passwd/username string $(username)
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $(password)
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string ubuntu
d-i debian-installer/locale string $(locale)
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string $(keyboard_layout)
d-i keyboard-configuration/variantcode string $(keyboard_variant)
```

All the `$(xxx)` are replaced by the Wubi installer - most are fairly straightforward, but my attempts to get the password correct failed (easily reset later).

Then it remains to boot the install with the preseed file:

```
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
search --set=diskroot -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $diskroot
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk preseed/file=/ubuntu/install/preseed.cfg wubi-diskimage ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
```

Anyway that's the easiest way to get Wubi manually installed. I recently did it on a Virtual machine running EFI firmware.

The other technique is to get `ubiquity` (the desktop installer) to install directly to the `root.disk`. This requires a preseed file as well. Wubi kicks off the installer via `grub4dos`, then uses the kernel extracted from the ISO to boot the ISO (which has been saved to disk). Then it preseeds the installer. This is a lot more complex than using the pre-installed disk image.

Comment: I see, so if I'm right it would be easier for me to create a pre-installed image. I am trying to create a UEFI Secure Boot compatible image that I will boot via GRUB2 for EFI outside of the .disk image

Comment: How difficult would it be to get ubiquity to install directly to the root.disk from a Live USB? Is it possible?

Comment: @Dan It's definitely possible. If it's a manual kickoff from a live USB you'll have to provide the preseed file. There will probably be some mods to grub/lupin for generating secure kernels once you have it running (and also automatic installation of Grub to the /efi partition to boot it). Have you tried asking in #ubuntu-installer on Freenode?